# Why am I converting a byte array to bitmap but bitmap back to null

Tags: android, arrays, bitmap

I don't know what the reason is, the byte array is non-null, but it cannot be converted to bitmap.I was converting the Bitmap to a byte array, then converting the array into a String to Greendao, converting the String to a byte array when it was fetched, and then converting the byte array to bitmap but getting a null value.

```
 public void showUserIconOnImg() {
        String userIconStr = (String) SharePrefenceHelper.get(mContext, "userIcon", "");
        byte[] iconByte = userIconStr.getBytes();
        Bitmap imgUserIcon = Bytes2Bimap(iconByte);
        ivUsericon.setImageBitmap(imgUserIcon);

    }

    private Bitmap Bytes2Bimap(byte[] b) {
        if (b.length != 0) {
            Bitmap bit = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length);
            return bit;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Here is debug result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZq7j.png)

Comment: your byte array is wrong - it cannot be decoded

Comment: What's your meaning ?  What should i do?

Comment: pass a valid data like: `00000000  89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a  00 00 00 0d 49 48 44 52  |.PNG........IHDR|` for a png image or `00000000  ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46  49 46 00 01 02 00 00 64  |......JFIF.....d|` for a jpg image

Comment: Can you tell me your solution?

Comment: `String userIconStr`. You cannot use a String instance to put the bytes of an image in. You have to come up with something better.

Comment: You can only hold an image in a string if you base64 encode the image bytes.

Comment: `then converting the array into a String to Greendao, ` ??? It is unclear what you are doing. How did you convert those bytes to a string?

Comment: Thanks ,I found a way to solve it.